# Convert infix to RPN ready postfix notation with exponents handling without parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, rpn

I'm trying to convert infix like this:

```
1+(9-6)^2+3
```

to RPN ready [Polish postfix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) format.

There is code for the purpose:

```
def toRPN(s):
    kv = {"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2, "^": 2, "(": 0, ")": 3}
    li = []
    ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")", "^"]
    result = ""
    for i in s:
        if i in ops:
            if i == "(":
                li.append(i)
            elif i == ")":
                while len(li) > 0 and li[-1] != "(":
                    p = li.pop()
                    result += p
                li.pop()
            elif len(li) == 0 or kv[li[-1]] < kv[i]:
                li.append(i)
            else:
                result += i
        else:
            result += i

    while len(li) > 0:
        result += li.pop()

    return result
```

Output for the given string is such: `196-2+3^+`.

But it's not correct output. Calculation of this expression will not be correct.

Expected output: `196-2^+3+`

I can achieve this with parentheses of course: `1+((9-6)^2)+3` and output will be correct as expected: `196-2^+3+`. But I want to achieve behavior like in Chrome console (prioritize exponents without parentheses). Screenshot:

But I can't achieve such behavior.

[image]

Code for RPN calculation:

```
import operator

ops = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub, "*": operator.mul, "/": operator.truediv, "^": operator.pow}

def evalRPN(s):
    st = []
    for tk in s:
        if tk in ops:
            b, a = st.pop(), st.pop()
            r = ops[tk](a, b)
        else:
            r = float(tk)
        st.append(r)
    return st.pop()
```

**EDIT:**

I find out the converter generate incorrect expression for simple input even like this: `1+9-4`.
For such input it was generate RPN like this: `19-4+` when should: `19+4-`.
So with debugger I fixed the converter behavior with adding the following:

```
if len(li) and li[-1] not in ['(', ')']:
    result += li.pop()
```

for the case when `i` is not operator (on line 19).
And change priorities to `{"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2, "^": 3, "(": 0, ")": 4}`

So my code now:

```
def toRPN(s: str) -> str:
    priority = {"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2, "^": 3, "(": 0, ")": 4}
    li = []
    ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")", "^"]
    result = ""
    for i in s:
        if i in ops:
            if i == "(":
                li.append(i)
            elif i == ")":
                while len(li) > 0 and li[-1] != "(":
                    p = li.pop()
                    result += p
                li.pop()
            elif len(li) == 0 or priority[li[-1]] < priority[i]:
                li.append(i)
            else:
                result += i
        else:
            result += i
            if len(li) and li[-1] not in ['(', ')']:
                result += li.pop()

    while len(li) > 0:
        result += li.pop()

    return result
```

But after that change I got problems with some simple expressions like this `"3+5/2"`. Before that "fix" it's worked right without parentheses. **So my general question is** how to fix the algorithm such that can handle all expressions correctly.

Comment: You say your expected output is `196-2^+3+`, but that does *not* appear to be valid `RPN`.

Comment: @Booboo but how it should look? First expression in parentheses `(9 - 6)` -> `96-` then raise the result to the power of two `96-2^` then add to the result 1 then 3 -> `19+3+`. Isn't it right?

Comment: I was seeing 196 as a single number so `196-` clearly looked wrong. Your output will look clearer (and more correct if you put a space between your numbers and operators: `1 9 6 - 2 ^ + 3 +`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m said above, you don't have loop with pop operators with greater priority (or equal priority to left-associative). You do it for brackets only. I do not how small edit your code to correct but it is correct:

```py
def toRPN(s: str) -> str:
    priority = {"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2, "^": 3, "(": -1, ")": 0}
    right_associative_operators = {"^"}
    li = []
    ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")", "^"]
    result = ""
    for i in s:
        if i in ops:
            if i == "(":
                li.append(i)
            else:
                while li and (
                    priority[li[-1]] > priority[i] or
                    priority[li[-1]] == priority[i] and i not in right_associative_operators
                ):
                    result += li.pop()
                if i == ')':
                    li.pop()
                else:
                    li.append(i)
        else:
            result += i

    while li:
        result += li.pop()

    return result
```

I set `priority["("]` as -1 and `priority[")"]` as 0 to don't write a separate loop for brackets and other operators.

This condition:

```py
priority[li[-1]] == priority[i] and i not in right_associative_operators
```

to correct work with right-associative operators. If it is unnecessary then you can use simpler the condition:

```py
while li and priority[li[-1]] >= priority[i]:
```

Some outputs:

```py
toRPN('1+(9-6)^2+3') = '196-2^+3+'
toRPN('1+9-4') = '19+4-'
toRPN('2^3^4') = '234^^'
toRPN('1+2+3+4') = '12+3+4+'
```

Comment: You should have spaces between numbers and operators. How do I know that the first number is not a 12? The idea of RPN is then to be able to evaluate it to come up with the final result, which is easy to do with a stack. But if I scan your last example's result I am going to push on the stack a 12 Next I see a '+' operator for which I should pop off *two* operands from the stack and add them together, which will clearly lead to an error. The results should instead be: `1 2 + 3 + 4 +`

Comment: @Booboo look at the given evalRPN function - it works with digits only. If you need a number greater than 9, of course, will need to split the input string into tokens (numbers and operators) and get the result with some separator (as an example it will be space).

Comment: Yes, what you say about the `evalRPN` is true and given that implementation, you are correct. I would, of course, say that that `evalRPN` implementation leaves much to be desired. What would it have taken to take the input string and split it on whitespace and then iterate the elements of the resulting list?

Comment: @Booboo add spaces to input string? Input string doesn't have spaces. Yes, we can process also the input string without spaces, but the question was about another.

Comment: *Not* the original *infix* input string. I meant to have the function `toRPN` generate RPN with spaces and then have `evalRPN` modified to split on spaces and in that way one could handle integers and floating point numbers of arbitrary size.

Comment: @Booboo What is a problem? Replace `result = ""` to `result = []` and get toRPN('1+9-4') = ['1', '9', '+', '4', '-'].

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is incorrect. Look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail) describing the algorithm:

```
- an operator o1:
    while (
        there is an operator o2 other than the left parenthesis at the top
        of the operator stack, and (o2 has greater precedence than o1
        or they have the same precedence and o1 is left-associative)
    ):
        pop o2 from the operator stack into the output queue
    push o1 onto the operator stack
```

Your code:

```
        elif len(li) == 0 or priority[li[-1]] < priority[i]:
            li.append(i)
        else:
            result += i
```

is missing the entire `while` part, abd the `else` part in it comes from nowhere. You are not supposed to copy *any* operator directly to the output.

Also bear in mind that `^` is usually considered right-associative while all other normal operators are left-associative. Your code does not take associativity into account (which may or may not be within your design parameters).